# How to get the country value based on the country code?

Tags: php, laravel

This code "`$countries = Facades\Countries::all();`" returns the country code and code value like:

```
  "DE" => "Germany"
```

I want to store the user country in the db when the user select the country in a select menu

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="country" class="text-gray">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)
            <option value="{{$key}}">{{$country}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

But with:

```
$user->country = $request->country;
$user-save();
```

In the db is stored "DE" but I want to store the country value like "Germany". Do you know how to based on the country code get the value so is possible to store the value and not the code?

Comment: What is the relationship between `$countries` and `$request->country`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the db is stored "DE" but I want to store the country value like "Germany".

You just need to use as:

```
$countries = Facades\Countries::all();
$user->country = $countries[$request->country];
```

Just make sure that `Facades\Countries::all()` does not have performance impact, i guess it pulls out data from db.

**OR**

Other solution is to remove `value` attribute from `option` tag.

```
<option>{{$country}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, replace `{{$key}}` with `{{$country}}` in option

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country" class="text-gray">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)
            <option value="{{$country}}">{{$country}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place country name in select options value as well. Replace `{{$key}}` with `{{$country}}`:

```
@foreach($countries as $country)
    <option value="{{$country}}">{{$country}}</option>
@endforeach
```